# Typescript issue using 'this' inside class constructor for instance method

Tags: javascript, typescript, export, instance, umd

I have a very simple use case in TypeScript: 
A class, with a constructor, and an instance method.

I want to call this instance method from the constructor, but using "this" resolves incorrectly.

What is the proper way to have a class with instance methods, and call them from the constructor?

I have a UMD module (defined in my tsconfig as the module type to compile as).

I have the following code:

```
export namespace TestNS {
    export class TestClass {
        // Fields
        testValue: string;

        constructor(val: string) {
            this.testValue = val;
            this.privateMethod();
        }

        private privateMethod() {
            console.log("private instance method");
        }
    }//TestClass class
}
```

And it compiles to:

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var TestNS;
    (function (TestNS) {
        var TestClass = /** @class */ (function () {
            function TestClass(val) {
                this.testValue = val;
                this.privateMethod();
            }
            TestClass.prototype.privateMethod = function () {
                console.log("private instance method");
            };
            return TestClass;
        }()); //TestClass class
        TestNS.TestClass = TestClass;
    })(TestNS = exports.TestNS || (exports.TestNS = {}));
});
//# sourceMappingURL=Test.js.map
```

I call it using:

```
var ex = new TestNS.TestClass("test");
```

When invoking, I get an error that privateMethod cannot be found.
When debugging the raw js code in the browser, `this` in the class constructor seems to refer to "TestNS" namespace object, and NOT my TestClass instance I would expect. Why would this be? This seems like an obvious issue if I can't namespace, AND use class instance members.

What am I doing wrong here? (I want to enforce that kind of namespacing to organize objects and such for a larger project later)

Edit: To clarify how this code is loaded, I'll provide those details.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./js",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots" : ["./js/lib/@types"],
    "module": "UMD"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="require.js"></script>
    <!-- Data main attribute avoided due to some environment constraints (ie: a CMS) -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Example Text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Test': 'modules/Test',
        }
    }
});

requirejs(["Test"],function(TestNS) {
    var t = new TestNS.TestClass("value");
}
```

Comment: Posting your top code plus your `var ex = new TestNS.TestClass("test");` line [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) seems to work as desired, `private instance method` gets printed

Comment: Hmm, I was unable to get that "pen" to work with my code. (not sure how it differentiates TS module code and raw js). 

It works if I don't namespace the class, but I want the namespace. Is there a special way to do this, that I'm missing?

Answer (score -1):

The important bit happens to be the part that you haven't added to your question... how you load that code.

```
var ex = new TestNS.TestClass("test");
```

Will error if your previous code is not loaded, either by adding a script tag before the dependent code or by importing the module...

```
import { TestNS } from './test.js'
```

I imagine this is the missing piece.

Comment: I load this using RequireJS. My module loads, and the TestNS.TestClass IS found. 

I omitted this part because it was working as expected, and not needed. If you paste this code directly into the chrome console (the compiler output) it behaves as I indicate.

Comment: Show us how you import it.

Comment: I updated my post, showing how it's loaded. 

It shouldn't change my issue, but it's there if there actually is a problem there.